# Luke Lucene BooleanQuery

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net, luke

In Luke, the following search expression returns 23 results:

```
docurl:www.siteurl.com  docfile:Tomatoes*
```

If I pass this same expression into my C# Lucene.NET app with the following implementation:

```
        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(indexName);
        Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        try
        {
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("docurl", new StandardAnalyzer());
            BooleanQuery bquery = new BooleanQuery();
            Query parsedQuery = parser.Parse(query);
            bquery.Add(parsedQuery, Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            int _max = searcher.MaxDoc();
            BooleanQuery.SetMaxClauseCount(Int32.MaxValue);
            TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(parsedQuery, _max)
            ...
        }
```

I get 0 results

Luke is using StandardAnalyzer and this is what the Explain Structure window looks like:
[image: Luke Query Structure]

Must I manually create `BooleanClause` objects for each field I search on, specifying `Should` for each one then add them to the `BooleanQuery` object with `.Add()`?  I thought the `QueryParser` would do this for me.  What am I missing?

**Edit:**
Simplifying a tad, `docfile:Tomatoes*` returns 23 docs in Luke, yet 0 in my app.  Per Gene's suggestion, I've changed from `MUST` to `SHOULD`:

```
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("docurl", new StandardAnalyzer());
            BooleanQuery bquery = new BooleanQuery();
            Query parsedQuery = parser.Parse(query);
            bquery.Add(parsedQuery, Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            int _max = searcher.MaxDoc();
            BooleanQuery.SetMaxClauseCount(Int32.MaxValue);
            TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(parsedQuery, _max);
```

parsedQuery is simply `docfile:tomatoes*`

**Edit2:**

I think I've finally gotten to the root problem:

```
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("docurl", new StandardAnalyzer());
            Query parsedQuery = parser.Parse(query);
```

In the second line, `query` is `"docfile:Tomatoes*"`, but `parsedQuery` is `{docfile:tomatoes*}`.  Notice the difference?  Lower case 't' in the parsed query.  I never noticed this before.  If I change the value in the IDE to 'T', 23 results return.

I've verified that `StandardAnalyzer` is being used when indexing and reading the index.  How do I force `queryParser` to keep the case of the value of `query`?

**Edit3:**
Wow, how frustrating.  According to the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#setLowercaseExpandedTerms%28boolean%29), I can accomplish this with:

parser.setLowercaseExpandedTerms(false);

> Whether terms of wildcard, prefix,
>   fuzzy and range queries are to be
>   automatically lower-cased or not.
>   Default is true.

I won't argue whether that's a sensible default or not.  I suppose SimpleAnalyzer should have been used to lowercase everything in and out of the index.  The frustrating part is, at least with the version I'm using, Luke defaults the other way!  At least I learned a bit more about Lucene.

Comment: What's an example value of the variable "query"?  Also, what is the purpose of "bquery"?

Comment: I would assume query is the string he is searching on: docurl:www.siteurl.com  docfile:Tomatoes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryParser` will indeed take a query like "docurl:www.siteurl.com  docfile:Tomatoes*" and build a proper query out of it (boolean query, range query, etc.) depending on the query given (see [query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html)).

Your first step should be to attach a debugger and inspect the value and type of `parsedQuery`.

Comment: parsedQuery = docurl:www.toledoblade.com docfile:tomatoes*.  So it looks like the QueryParser is doing it's thing.

Comment: What is the type of parsedQuery?  It should be a boolean query and be composed of two other queries (matching the query structure you see in Luke).  Two questions: 1 - what it is the purpose of bquery (it doesn't seem to be used at all)? 2 - Do you get the same results if you use another different search method (one of the other overloads)?

Comment: You're right about bquery, I never noticed it isn't used.  I didn't write this code.  Looking into this now.

Comment: The reason for using `bquery` is to specify more than one search term, which is when the MUST/SHOULD distinction will come into play.

Comment: `bquery` is not used as an argument to the `IndexSearcher` though.

Comment: Changing the last line to TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(bquery, _max); doesn't seem to have helped either.  Still 0 hits.

Comment: Right, I don't think `bquery` is necessary here at all.  Sorry, I can see how my last comment might have suggested that.  The `QueryParser` will take your query expression (`docurl:www.toledoblade.com docfile:tomatoes*`) and turn it into the proper query structure (a `BooleanQuery` composed of a `TermQuery` and `PrefixQuery`).  I would suggest digging into `parsedQuery` in the debugger and looking to see what it is composed of.  There should be a queries collection/enumerable/array inside of `parsedQuery`.

Comment: Got it, I see both the TermQuery and PrefixQuery in the clauses collection.  Both have an occur member that seems to be blank {} of type Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.  If I prefix both field names with '+' then the value for the occur variable for both is {+}, which based on Gene's comment seems to force MUST.  Is there any way to add something in the query expression to force a SHOULD?  If not, do you have any suggestions for how else I can default to SHOULD in my parsedQuery BooleanQuery object?

Comment: The default `BooleanClause` for `QueryParser` is SHOULD, so that's not likely the problem.  Without more information, I can't really say why it's not working.  All I can suggest is to try different queries, try an index with only a few documents in it.  Just try to control the environment to so you can do some experiments.

Comment: You both helped, but Ryan gave more input.  Points to him.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Occur.MUST` is equivalent to using the `+` operator with the standard query parser. Thus you code is evaluating `+docurl:www.siteurl.com +docfile:Tomatoes*` rather than the expression you typed into Luke. To get that behavior, try `Occur.SHOULD` when adding your clauses.

Comment: Changing my search expression in Luke to +docurl:www.toledoblade.com +docfile:Tomatoes* does indeed return 0 docs.  However, changing my clause to SHOULD doesn't seem to have the reverse effect.  bquery.Add(parsedQuery, Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);.  hits.totalHits is still 0.

Comment: try searching on `bquery' rather than on `parsedQuery`, and, as @ryan mentioned below, see what the class of `parsedQuery` is. Stepping through the code in the debugger is often helpful.